# Why did my Raspberry Pi 4 stop playing sound?

Tags: audio, driver, update

Two updates ago, my Pi 4 just stopped playing sound and I tried doing another update/upgrade combo and still nothing. Could this be a corrupted sound driver? How can I fix this? I purchased the Pi 4 with the OS pre-loaded on the SD card and so it's never been edited by me at all...in case anyone was thinking of mentioning that... I'm not very experienced with the Pi, so please take this into consideration.

Please help, and thank you

Answer (score 0):

check your config file first, make sure these lines are not commented out

```
     Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
    dtparam=audio=on
```

also see what your dtoverlay is, I use a DAC line out hat so mine is

```
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac
```